# How to open a url in a new window?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, window

I want to know how to open a url in a new window?
I have seen a web site, when I click a link, a new window appears.
Not a new tab, but a new window, and the new window is smaller than I already have.
I'm guessing there's also some way to control the height and width of the window?
How to do that? How to write the code?

Comment: Google is your friend -> `How to open a url in a new window`

Comment: A new, smaller browser? Wouldn't that be something!

Comment: -1 there are solutions all over google and there's a duplicate right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [open a new window inside same page in a small size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498621/open-a-new-window-inside-same-page-in-a-small-size)

Comment: sorry,I really have try to use the window.open() before,I find It just open the new tab.I see I am not carefully now. Thanks all your help...　English is not my language ,It is hard to read many English articles.So I just ask,very sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507661/how-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-window","this is a new window")`, but please don't add that to this page, or you might get a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507661/how-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-window)